# When is the isotypical decomposition of a representation not unique?

Tags: representation-theory, irreducible-representation

I am reading some notes on representation theory, and I have found myself confused by the following proposition:

*Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group, then every complex representation $V$ of $G$ has a unique isotypical decomposition*

I have also read that this is true in the case of $G$ non-abelian, and if the characteristic of the scalar field does not divide $|G|$.

The isotypical decomposition is only defined for $V$ a completely reducible representation:
$$ 
V\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I} V_i
$$
and the notes define the isotypical decomposition to be unique if $V$ is the direct product of all $S$-isotypic components as $S$ varies over all irreducible subrepresentations of $V$ (up to isomorphism).

The $S$-isotypic component can be realised as $\sum_{V_i\cong S} V_i$. I am confused because if $\sum_{i\in I}V_i=\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i$, then surely $\sum_{V_i\cong S}V_i=\bigoplus_{V_i\cong S}V_i$ , hence all isotypical decompositions would be unique? This would be because $\bigoplus_{S \text{ irreducible and unique up to isomorphism}}\bigoplus_{V_i\cong S}V_i=\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i\cong V$.

What's gone wrong here? What breaks when $|G|$ is a multiple of the characteristic (or when $G$ is infinite)? I have not learnt about characters yet, so if answers could avoid using those, that would be appreciated.

Comment: which notes are you reading?

Comment: They are the 2023 notes by Simon Wadsley

Comment: a good example for you to consider would be G the cyclic group of order two, k the field with two elements, and V the free kG-module of rank 1.

Comment: I see, so is the key point that a $V_i$ may occur with multiplicity $>1$, and so the $V_i$-isotypic component will then only contain one copy of $V_i$? If so, would it be true to say that $V$ has a unique isotypical decomposition iff the $V_i$ all occur with multiplicity 1?